# How can I use markdown for my main index file in a Nanoc site?

Tags: nanoc

I want to rename `content/index.html` to `content/index.md` and use markdown, but my rule for `/index/` is being ignored; `nanoc show-rules` shows it compiling it using more generic rules.

How do I set rules for the index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to use `compile '/'` to match `content/index.md`.

This is what the [documentation](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/4-basic-concepts/#items) means when it says:

> There is one “root” or “home” page which has identifier /